# Create a database stored procedure from .NET?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to create a stored procedure in my database from within C# code.

How can I do this?

FOR INSTANCE:  Using Microsoft SQL Server, I just want to create a stored procedure `sp_GetUsers` in the database that takes an `int` parameter `userid` and a simple statement such as

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = @userid
```

This would be great because I could check the DB for the existence of that stored procedure, and if it doesn't, I just create from within code.

Comment: Create a procedure? Or invoke one? Can you give an example of the scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run arbitrary DDL statements:

```
new SqlCommand(@"CREATE PROCEDURE ...").ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. All you have to do is execute a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement via your open DB connection. If you can give us an example of your DB connection/query code right now, along with the DB vendor you're using (i.e. MS SQL, DB2), then we could probably give you a hard and fast example.